# Is component an attribute of HTML5 or a protoype.js thing?

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

Is **component** an attribute of HTML5 or part of prototype.js?
I'm not having any luck finding information online about this. I think component and attribute are too generic of terms to be searched well.

Example (from http://flixster.rottentomatoes.com/):

```
<li id="" class="active" component="NavigationButton">
    ...
</li>
```

Then take a look at the nav element and the li elements contained within.
Not sure how to paste HTML as an example here. Note: feel free to edit my code to give example

Comment: `component` is not an attribute of any HTML5 element.  An easy way to check is at Simon Pieter's HTML5 element and attribute list: http://simon.html5.org/html-elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a custom attribute read by the Component Object Model which is some custom framework.

It reads the attribute as follows:

```
tags.each(function(tag) {
    var name = $(tag).readAttribute("component");
    try {
        new Component[name](tag);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error initializing Component." + name + " - " + err);
    }
});
```

Basically creates a new Component instance depending on what the attribute value was. I.E. if an element had `component="Form"`, the framework would create a new `Component.Form` instance around that element. It's very [Flexy](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex.html).

Comment: Is this a flixster/rottentomatoes custom codebase? Weird that they would choose the name Component Object Model since that name has been used for years by Microsoft for COM.

Comment: @brun the framework is defined in this file: http://static.flixstercdn.com/static/v/glo20101121/scripts/global.js Search for "Component Object Model"

Comment: Thanks I missed that section of code the first time. Didn't scroll down enough.